# After MacTeX manual update how should I remove the old one?

Tags: texlive, installing, mac, updating

MacTeX 2014 is installed on OS X. But how can I remove the old one? Or is it automatically overwritten?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just go to the `/usr/local/texlive` folder: do `Command-Alt-G` from the Finder and type `/usr/local/texlive` in the box

[image]

You'll be presented with folders named `texmf-local`, `2013` and `2014`:

[image]

(I still have the 2012 version for testing).

Drag the `2013` folder to the trashcan; the system will ask for an Administrator password. Empty the trash. End of MacTeX 2013.

***Don't touch the `texmf-local` folder!***

Be sure to do  this *only* when you're sure that your current projects compile properly with the new version. If you don't have disk space problems, leave the old version where it is: with the TeX Distribution control panel you can switch among the available distributions.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! And where is this control panel?

Comment: @user3058699 It's installed in System Preferences

Comment: Update: the choice between distribution releases is now done in TeX Live Utility (the control panel no longer exists).