# \pic: undefined control sequence

Tags: tikz-pgf, errors

I am using  Texmaker on Macbook but I have a problem with my code. When I run my code it always shows this message:

> "undefined control sequence \pic".

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
\usepackage{xcolor,pict2e}% to allow any radius

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
  \tikzset{pics/myarc/.style args={inner #1 and outer #2 with fill #3}{
  code={
    \draw[very thick, #1] (1,0) arc (0:90:1cm);
    \draw[very thick] (0,1) -- (0,2.2);
    \draw[very thick, #2] (0,2.2) arc (90:0:2.2cm);
    \draw[very thick] (2.2,0) -- (1,0);
    \fill[#3] (1,0) arc (0:90:1cm) -- (0,2.2) arc (90:0:2.2cm) -- cycle;
  }
}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[very thick,<->] (-6,0) -- (6,0)node[anchor=north west] {$x$};
\pic [draw,very thick, rotate=-45]      {myarc={inner blue!90 and outer blue with fill green!}};\end{tikzpicture}\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome! What version of MacTeX are you using? If you are not using an updated 2014 installation, update to ensure that you have the current version of TiKZ. In particular, if you are using a version of TiKZ prior to 3, it will not work.

Comment: Your code compiles fine. You almost certainly just need to update. Also, you don't need to load `pict2e`. I don't know why your comment says it allows 'any radius'. And `xcolor` is loaded by `tikz` already. But none of that is a problem. It still compiles fine.

Comment: Probably related: [After MacTeX manual update how should I remove the old one?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/225483/after-mactex-manual-update-how-should-i-remove-the-old-one)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem should have been resolved with an up-to-date distribution and version of TikZ/PGF.